# FFmpeg - Check if folder contains a matching filename with 2 different extensions and ignore both files. Process only filenames with 1 extension

Tags: batch-file, type-conversion

I need to batch convert all mkv files in a folder recursively to mp4.

If a filename exists and matches both extensions, ignore both files and process only filenames that contain mkv, without matching mp4.

Example: `cat.mkv` exists in folder with `cat.mp4` = ignore both files

Example: `cat.mkv` exists in folder and `cat.mp4` does not = process `cat.mkv` to `cat.mp4`

I have included a script that doesn't work well. It processes all mkv files and mp4 files. The mp4 files throw an error as FFmpeg will not encode the same format in this manner over itself.

As always thank you to anyone who might have a few ideas.

**UPDATE:** I may have gotten it to work. I changed a few things from the original. If anyone has success or an idea to improve I'm all ears. Thanks.

VERSION 2

```
@ECHO ON
SETLOCAL
PROMPT $G
COLOR 0A

REM Set FFmpeg.exe location if not in system PATH already
SET FF=C:\MAB\local64\bin-video\ffmpeg.exe

REM Set MKV files root folder to recursively search
SET "mkvPATH=C:\Encoding\1_Original\Test\"

REM Change into mkvPATH DIR
CD "C:\Encoding\1_Original\Test"

REM Set temp file name
SET TEMPFILE=convert_mkv.bat

REM Create empty convert file
COPY NUL "%TEMPFILE%" >NUL 2>&1

REM ADD @ECHO OFF to top of blank convert_mkv.bat script
ECHO @ECHO OFF >>"%TEMPFILE%"

REM Recursively search MKV root folder
FOR /R "%mkvPATH%" %%G IN (*.mkv *.mp4) DO (
    SET "GPATH=%%~fG"
    SET "GNAME=%%~nG"
    SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

    REM Ignore all files that have both
    REM extensions ".mkv" and ".mp4" in the file name
    IF "%%~nG.mkv"=="%%~nG.mkv" (
        IF NOT EXIST "%%~nG.mp4" (
            CALL :DO_FFmpeg "!GPATH!"
            IF "%%~nG.mkv"=="%%~nG.mkv" (
                IF EXIST "%%~nG.mp4" (
                    ECHO(>>"%TEMPFILE%"
                ) ELSE ENDLOCAL
            )
        )
    )
)
GOTO END

REM CALL variables for use in FFmpeg's command line
:DO_FFmpeg
IF "%~1"=="" GOTO :END
FOR %%I IN ("%~1") DO (
    SET "FOLDER=%%~dpI"
    SET "NAME=%%~nxI"
)

REM Export info to "%TEMPFILE% and RUN ffmpeg.exe's command line in the cmd.exe window
ECHO %FF% -y -i "%~1" -ss 0 -t 300 -codec copy "%FOLDER%%~n1.mp4">>"%TEMPFILE%" && %FF% | %FF% -y -i "%~1" -ss 600 -t 30 -codec copy "%FOLDER%%~n1.mp4"

:END
PAUSE
EXIT /B
```

Comment: `for %%G in ("*.mkv") do if not exist "%%~nG.mp4" echo Do something...`?

Comment: Great and simple, I think with additional code it will work fine. I'll let you know if I conjure up something. I think my second revision works ok now as well.